# Firebase Stripe Extension updating product and not customer

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

As the title suggests, I am trying to add a customer in both my Stripe console and my cloud firestore database. I can add a customer using the Stripe console, however, nothing seems to happen in cloud firestore. For added context, adding a product in the Stripe console works totally as expected and adds a document to the correct location in my database.

Comment: The extension source code does seem to indicate that when a user record [1] is created, it will try and create a customer on Stripe. Have you tried invoking your firebase function and see if it creates a customer on Stripe? 

[1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L53

Comment: I created my own cloud function which works for now but it doesn't have the seamless transition as seems to be offered in the documentation. I looked at the code for the extension created functions and it seems like it is still trying to get data from "customers" when I specified "users" in the configuration?

Comment: Hmm quite possible.